# How to modify JSON data and then POST it to a URL?

Tags: java, json

I am writing a java code which controls a robot in the MRDS environment. The data about the robot (position, speed, etc) can be obtained from a URL(http://localhost:50000). This data is in the JSON format. I think that I have to modify these files in order to control the robot. The problem I have now is to POST data to that URL.

I want to modify the JSON files that I am obtaining from this site, and then repost it, so that I can control the robot. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Jackson library to map to java objects or a tree, modify, and then use the Apache CXF JAX-RS client to send the new post.